# Why does this image look different in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I downloaded the following image and opened it in Adobe Illustrator:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg

[image]

For some reason, the image appears differently inside Illustrator than it does in a webpage. Why is this happening?
Here's what it looks like in Illustrator:
[image]

Comment: whats it look like in Illustrator? Can you take a screenshot so we can see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the stroke it will fix it (It did for me.)

Illustrator does not always read SVG data correctly,

https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/333657-illustrator-feature-requests/suggestions/31209892-fully-support-the-svg-standard